# circular dependency error for dataSource after adding spring DATA JPA

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-data-jpa, spring-security-oauth2

I am working in spring boot security with Oauth2. Oauth2 to makes use of jdbcAuthentication in AuthorizationServerConfigurerImpl. But in my webSecurityCofigurer implementing class i want to use Spring data JPA to implement userDetailsService. After enabling @EnableJpaRepositories it is throwing circular depenency error and not able to load dataSource which i am defining in AuthorizationServerConfigurerImpl.
Please help me resolving issue

Comment: add minimum code in question